# findViewById returns null in custom View after inflate

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

I have a custom `RelativeLayout` and I inflate an xml res file in it. 
This works fine if I use the custom layout in an xml file and set it as contentview, but if I try to add it in the code with `new LocationItem(this)` and `addChild()` the `findViewById` method always returns `null` in the constructor of the custom `RelativeLayout`.

Here is the code:

```
public class LocationItem extends RelativeLayout {

private String parcelType;
private int countIntoBox, countFromBox;

private RelativeLayout deliveryContainer, pickupContainer;

private TextView countPickup, countDelivery;

public LocationItem(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public LocationItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public LocationItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_location, this);
    deliveryContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_location_delivery_container);
    pickupContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_location_pickup_container);
    countPickup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location_pickup_count);
    countDelivery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location_delivery_count);

    countPickup.setOnClickListener(getShowNumberPickerListener());
    countDelivery.setOnClickListener(getShowNumberPickerListener());
}

private OnClickListener getShowNumberPickerListener() {
    return new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showNumberPickerDialog(view);
        }
    };
} ...
}
```

Add custom view in activity

```
mRootLayoutLocations.addView(new LocationItem(this));
```

The view is inflated correctly, because I can see it, but when I try to access a view inside the custom view the app crashes with a NullPointerException.

Comment: Your problem is that mRootLayoutLocations is null. It's not in the definition of this class.

Comment: Nope definitely not! mRootLayoutLocations is not null! This layout is in the activity where I add the LocationItems :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok i inflated the view into a View(holder)

```
View v = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_location, this);
```

and then access the views via v.findViewById. Now it's working.

Code:

```
View v = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_location, this);
deliveryContainer = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl_location_delivery_container);
pickupContainer = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl_location_pickup_container);
countPickup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_location_pickup_count);
countDelivery = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_location_delivery_count);

countPickup.setOnClickListener(getShowNumberPickerListener());
countDelivery.setOnClickListener(getShowNumberPickerListener());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using appropriate constructors, not overloading them.

```
public class LocationItem extends RelativeLayout {

    private String parcelType;
    private int countIntoBox, countFromBox;

    private RelativeLayout deliveryContainer, pickupContainer;

    private TextView countPickup, countDelivery;

    public LocationItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public LocationItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public LocationItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_location, this);
        deliveryContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_location_delivery_container);
        pickupContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_location_pickup_container);
        countPickup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location_pickup_count);
        countDelivery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location_delivery_count);

        countPickup.setOnClickListener(getShowNumberPickerListener());
        countDelivery.setOnClickListener(getShowNumberPickerListener());
    }

    private OnClickListener getShowNumberPickerListener() {
        return new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showNumberPickerDialog(view);
            }
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Same. Still the NullPointerException.

Comment: post your stack trace please... also are you setting it's required field of width and height in code? :)

Comment: Ok i inflated the view into a View(holder)
View v = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_location, this);
and then access the views via v.findViewById. 
Now it's working. Maybe the view is not attached to the rootview so fast?

Comment: Yes. Try like this         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_location, this, true);

Answer (score 0):

I fear you must inflate the view instead of finding it from nowhere.  The method

```
findindViewById(int Id)
```

must be called within the Actvity's onCreate or with a view within which the child view/widget you are trying to find is resides in.

If all of the child views resides in a single xml file(within single parent root)

```
View rootView=(View) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_location);
pickupContainer = (RelativeLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rl_location_pickup_container);
```

Comment: yep that is what i did - see comments below.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. init views in the method onFinishInflate().This method will be called called as the last phase of inflation, after all child views have been added.So you can avoid NPE.

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
public LocationItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   this = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_location,null);
   ...
```